# unable to refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in an action listener

Tags: java, swing

I am getting an error that says "**cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method**"

This is happening when I am trying to set up my timer referencing an action listener that I have constructed! This constructor simply displays a label and the timers desired effect is to run the action listener for 10 seconds but I can't get past this error. The code below shows he action listener and where he issue is occurring. I have put stars around the problematic areas. Thanks

```
**ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener() {                         
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {        
            lblgreenImage.setBounds(150,410,50,40);
            repaint();          
        }       
    };**


    btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {

            String username = txtUserName.getText();
            String accessCode = txtPin.getText();


            String dataSourceName = "securitysystem";
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;

            try{
                //Type of connection driver used    
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                //Connection variable or object param: dbPath, userName, password
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");

                Statement statement = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select username, pin from securitysystem.employee where username = '" + username + "' and pin = '" + accessCode + "'");

                boolean nomatches=true;
                while(rs.next())
                {   
                    String checkrs = rs.getString("username");
                    String checkPin = rs.getString("Pin");
                    if (username.equals(checkrs)) {
                        if (accessCode.equals(checkPin)) {
                            **Timer timer = new Timer(500, actListner);**
                            **timer.start();**
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Related `list on the right please.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you try to access local variable `lblgreenImage` in `AbstractClass`. For fixing that you can:

1) add `final` modifier for `lblgreenImage`, when you create that, like next :

```
final JLabel lblgreenImage = new JLabel("labeel");
```

2) make `lblgreenImage` as instance variable.

Read more about [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) in java.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are getting at, sorry i am quite new to all this. When I do this it says **cannot instantiate the type window.type**

Comment: edited, `Type` is a type of your `lblgreenImage`, seems it's `JLabel`

Comment: yes its JLabel and I have done that but how do I make lblGreenImage as instance variable :)

Comment: read link about variable, instance variable it's class variable determine in class, not in method.